# Bootstrap typeahead not setting the value for the field with updater callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am in development of a backbone application with a view having the following lines:

```
c.$(".itemName").typeahead({source:itemNames,updater:function(item){
c.$(".itemName").val(item);
}});
```

This is not setting the value of the text field. I have console logged the value of item variable and it gets logged correctly. Further i can easily access properties like

`c.$(".itemname").attr('class')`

This means that the element is accessible. just don't know why its not setting up the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updater function should **return** the value to be used. It's not responsible for actually setting it.  For example:

```
$(".itemName").typeahead({
    source: itemNames,
    updater: function(item) {
        // Opportunity to execute logic based on selected value
        // ...
        return item;
    }
});
```

That's how I interpreted it from the bootstrap v2.3.0 docs anyway...